# With Prisma, why do I have to add `[key: string]: any` to an interface to allow it to be assigned to a JSON column?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

For example, if I have an interface like this:

```
// This won't work
interface Metadata {
  title: string
  pages: number
}
```

and then I try to do an update on a JSON column in Prisma:

```
// The metadata property gets highlighted with a TS error
const book = await prisma.book.update({
  where: { id: 1 },
  data: { metadata: metadata },
})
```

I get an error that says:

```
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Metadata'
```

If I modify the interface to add `[key: string]: any` like this:

```
// This works
interface Metadata {
  title: string
  pages: number
  [key: string]: any
}
```

then the error goes away. Weirdly, if I define the `Metadata` as a type instead of an interface, then I don't get the error, even without the `[key: string]: any`

```
// This works too
type Metadata = {
  title: string
  pages: number
}
```

Basically, I want to understand this better so that I can better understand if I should be using a type or an interface for these JSON column values.

Comment: Did you find any answer to your question? If yes could you please answer your own question. I get a type error too.

Answer (score 1):

About the `type` vs `interface` part, I found this "rule of thumb": "use `type` for internal interfaces since I don't need augmentation and `interface` for external" to be accepted by Typescript team.

For more detail, I guess this [issue from Typescript's Github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) can help.